# Do Enumerable.ElementAt in the same iteration of Enumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm iterating through an `IEnumerable` like below.

```
IEnumerable<string> readFile = ... ;
int lineNumber = 1;

foreach (string readLine in readFile)
{
   ...

   lineNumber++;
}
```

But during the loop I have to check the next line. And I use `ElementAt` for this:

```
foreach (string readLine in readFile)
{
   ...
   if (readFile.ElementAt(lineNumber+1) == ...)
   {
      // Do something
   }

   lineNumber++;
}
```

When I use the above code with `ElementAt`, I get `Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable`

Can you explain this to me? Or is there another solution I can use? I have to use IEnumerable because I'm working with large files

Comment: If you use `File.ReadAllLines` instead of `File.ReadLines` to read the lines you'd get an array. Then you could use `ElementAt` without enumerating the whole file again and again. It's optimized in a way that it uses the indexer if it can be casted to `IList<T>`.

Comment: But, what about performance? Isn't ReadAllLines slower than ReadLines?

Comment: Not necessarily if the file is not that large. It's reading all into memory so it can be more expensive in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: The files are very large... 20.000 lines and even more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well any time you call `ElementAt`, if it's *just* a sequence (i.e. not an `IList<T>`) it will have to iterate all the way through the sequence as far as the given element number - there's no other way of it getting to the value.

It sounds like you should just have:

```
string previousLine = null;
foreach (var line in readFile)
{
    // Work with line and previousLine here, understanding that on the
    // first iteration it will be null

    previousLine = line;
}
```

Comment: @Ozkan: Assuming you can't do anything with just the first line of the file, yes.

Comment: @Ozkan: Well that requires a slightly different solution. Is there anything else you'd need? I don't want to keep giving different bits of code and then have the requirements change again...

Comment: @Ozkan: Okay, I'll edit my answer - but please, next time make sure you describe your *whole* problem in the question.

Comment: @Ozkan: Actually, it's still not clear what you need - can you just use `previousLine` and `line` in the loop I've given you, and then *after* the loop, `previousLine` will be the final line of the file. If not, please edit your question to explain what you actually need to do.

Comment: @Ozkan: Sorry, it's still not sufficiently clear that I'm willing to spend time writing code which could easily end up being completely useless to you. Please update your question with more details, and then I'll see what I can do.